# Game Maker Studio Networking Client to Server Communication

Tags: networking, server, game-maker-studio-2

I'm working on multiplayer, I can at the moment send data to the client, however, my server can't seem to receive data from the client.

I have a feeling I'm missing something in my Async Networking event, but I'm unsure. Here is a sample of the server to client code and what I'm trying to do.

the listeners are just lists, I can't post any more links to images so I hope this is enough.

[Connection Listener Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydx8S.png)

[Server Async](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPxgG.png)

[OnNetworkAsyncEvent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nToxK.png)

[serverSendClientID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkzCG.png)

[clientDataListener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wQVH.png)

[serverDataListener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPfDh.png)

[ClientHandler create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhS2E.png)

[serverHandler create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duPpe.png)

Comment: Next time when you paste code, you can just post the actual code inside the question. Thats much easier to read (and potentially edit) for us than linking screenshots of code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was wrong, the serverHandler needed to have an else statement then run through the data listener scripts as it was only checking the servers own socket.

Comment: Please mark your question as answered if you fixed it! :)

Comment: how? I'm still new to this site.

Comment: You can click the checkmark on the left here, under the voting buttons :)